# Calculating set. Did I do it right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have done this assignment in my homework, and I am not sure if I did it in the right way. So maybe you can help me.

So this is the assignment.

> Write all elements in the set: 
>   $$
> V:=\left\{a\in\mathbb{R}\;\middle|\;a<0\text{ and }\sqrt{4a+4a^2+1}=1\right\}
> $$

I did this set like this. I calculated quadratic equation:
$$
\sqrt{4a+4a^2+1}=1\;\to\;\sqrt{(2a+1)^2}=1
$$
Then I just simply solved the equation for the $a$, and then I got that this is a empty set, because $a$ is smaller than $0$, and I have logical "and" Operator.

Did I do this in the right manner? If I did something wrong please advise me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^2 =1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is almost right...You forgot that when $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ (the absolute value of $x$).

So you get $V= \{ a\ \in \mathbb R ∣a<0\ \text{ and }\ |2a+1|=1 \}$. Could you finish with that?

Comment: Thanks. I tried solving it, and I got that a=0 and a=-1, so the set is only -1. Is this right?

Comment: Yes at the end, you should get $V = \{ -1 \}$.